# Creating an equals method

Tags: java, equals

As per an assignment, I have to create a method called "equals" to do the following:

> The method compares the instance variables of the calling object with instance variables
>   of the parameter object for equality and returns `true` if the dollars and the cents of
>   the calling object are the same as the dollars and the cents of the parameter object.
>   Otherwise, it returns `false`.

UPDATE: I made a mistake and put the wrong thing, updated it. Got a new error:

```
Money.java:115: error: long cannot be dereferenced
  if (dollars.equals(otherObject.dollars) &&
             ^
Money.java:116: error: long cannot be dereferenced
     cents.equals(otherObject.cents))
          ^
2 errors
```

With the method:

```
   public boolean equals(Money otherObject)
{
  boolean status;

  if (dollars.equals(otherObject.dollars) &&
     cents.equals(otherObject.cents))
    return status = true;
  else
    return status = false;
}
```

Comment: Does your `Money` class define a `symbol` instance variable?

Comment: Can you post the Money class/interface?

Comment: cannot find symbol `symbol`

Comment: You'll need to return `status` at the end of `equals`.

Comment: Btw, that's not a valid `equals` override.

Comment: Be careful with the ``dollars == otherObject.dollars`` comparison. If ``dollars`` is a primitive type (i.e. ``int``, or ``long``, etc) your comparison is fine, but if ``dollars`` is an object type (say, a ``Dollar`` class, for example), then your comparison might not be good enough, and you should also use ``dollars.equals(otherObject.dollars)``.

Comment: Also, you forgot to add ``return status;``.

Comment: @Gonzalo - The cents and dollars are both longs. Thanks for the reminder about the return, forgot.

Comment: (otherObject.symbol.GETSYMBOL() when you try to access private members of the class

Comment: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~kmammen/documents/java/howToOverrideEquals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `dollars` and `cents` primitive `long` types?

You'd want to use (dollars == otherObject.dollars) && (cents == otherObject.cents) if they are.  You can't call a method (such as `equals()`) on a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

So both of your errors are trying to tell you that for whatever reason, your `Money` class doesn't have a field called `symbol`. So I'd confirm what the name of that field is before anything else and correct that.

You also need a `return status;` line, as outlined in the comments below your question.

Finally, and perhaps requiring the biggest change of all, you don't have the method signature for [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) correct. As you can see from the JavaDoc, the method is meant to take an `Object` as a parameter, not another instance of `Money`. Typically you'd do something like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null || !(object instanceof Money)) {
        return false;
    }

    Money other = (Money) object;

    return this.value.equals(other.value)
            && this.secondField.equals(other.secondField)
            && this.primitiveField == other.primitiveField;
}
```

Since primitive types (`int`s, `long`s, etc.) don't have any methods on them (including `.equals()`, you have to compare these fields using `==` rather than `.equals()`, as shown in the example above.

This isn't the most complete solution (there's plenty of good information answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)), and you should also override [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) if you're modifying `equals()`, to keep them *consistent*.

Comment: I checked, I don't know why I put symbol. My 2 instance fields are longs called "dollars" and "cents". This has cause a new error though so I'mma make an edit. Must of absent-mindedly put symbol.

Comment: @WillBro Updated to include comparison of primitive (e.g. `long`) fields, which is what's causing your new error.

Comment: Need to check if `object` is null first and if it is return false.

Comment: Also need to check `this.getClass() != other.getClass()`.. instanceOf does the same thing too

Comment: Thanks @GIJoe - was typed in a bit of a hurry, and I have to admit to generally using IDE generated `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods as starting points most of the time!